# Заменить ключи массива данными из БД mysql

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sometable`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
????ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ ПИСАТЬ????
}

Ниже приведена структура массива, в который хочется вынести данные из БД:

$nodes = array (

```
1 => 'вася', 
2 => 'петя', 
3 => 'кузя'
```

);

Задача следующая: нужно каким то образом заменить значения ключей массива на значения поля, допустим, id(там цифры не по порядку, каких то нет - в результате удаления записей), а им должны соответствовать данные из той же строки(то есть, например, $varisBD[id] => '$varisBD[name]').

Comment: Ну и конкретно в чем проблема? Код где, что заполняет этот массив?

Comment: Ключ - $row[id], значение - $row[name]. Доходит?

Comment: Да, я понимаю как вытащить из бд все это... я не понимаю как все это впихнуть в массив и как это вызывать, чтобы использовать.(даже просто вывести на экран.)

Comment: Спасибо всем, решил вопрос с помощью array_combine

Comment: А обычный синтаксис с [] не пробовали?

Comment: И кстати расширение mysql_ уже не используется.

Comment: а можете написать, как бы это сделали Вы? И что криминального в использовании mysql_?